# Parse Python Function's Class Name

Tags: python, regex, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to find the class name where a function name is called.

E.g. suppose I have:

```
class foo1(object):
    bar1()

class foo2(object):
    bar2()

class foo3(object):
    bar3()
```

If I am searching for bar2() I want to receive:

```
class foo2(object):
    bar2()
```

I tried regex `class[\s\S]*bar2\(\)(?!class)` with the idea being that I would negative lookahead for another appearance of class. Unfortunately it looks like the [\s\S] is already matching everything: https://regex101.com/r/kZ7eE5/1

Is there a way to match if "class" appears only one time while matching on all other chars (including new line and tab)?

Also alternatives that do not require regex would be accepted.

Comment: Why are you parsing Python with regular expressions?

Comment: Your chances might be better just scanning one line after the other and memorizing the last class definition you encountered. Also, what about nested classes, or methods, or methods _with_ nested classes?

Comment: I want to analyze the code base. Is there another tool that I can parse Python with?

Comment: Not used it myself, but https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html might be worth a look, or the `ast`(https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module.

Comment: @tobias_k yea I'll try that. Good point about the nested classes - in that case I would want just the closest level class. If the method is in a method which is in a class, I would want that class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RE approach can be error prone (the expressive power of Python language is more that those of the regular languages recognized by REs).

Use Python's `ast` module to parse Python code:

```
code = '''
class foo1(object):
    bar1()

class foo2(object):
    bar2()

class foo3(object):
    bar3()
'''

>>> import ast
>>> tree = ast.parse(code)
>>> for i in tree.body:
...     if isinstance(i, ast.ClassDef):
...         print('class: %s' % i.name)
...
class: foo1
class: foo2
class: foo3
>>>
```

and you can do many other things, check the docs at https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Edit: a more complete example:

```
>>> for i in tree.body:
...     if isinstance(i, ast.ClassDef):
...         for j in i.body:
...             if isinstance(j, ast.Expr):
...                 print('found a call to function %s in class %s' % (j.value.func.id, i.name))
...
found a call to function bar1 in class foo1
found a call to function bar2 in class foo2
found a call to function bar3 in class foo3
```

Comment: This doesn't serve OPs purpose, he wants to return a class that contains a certain function call

Comment: @PruthviRaj It's not complete, but it certainly works better than using regex.

Comment: @mescalinum , +1 this is perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code prints the class that contains the method call that is stored in `function` variable .Here's what you need to do :

```
import re

data = """
class foo1(object):
    bar1()

class foo2(object):
    bar2()

class foo3(object):
    bar3()
"""

classes = re.findall('(class[\s\S]*?)(?=class|$)',data)
function = "bar2()"
for x in classes:
    if function in x:
        matched_class = x
        break
print(matched_class)
```

Output:

```
class foo2(object):
    bar2()
```

Comment: Now try to use this to find a method named `get_class()` or similar.

Comment: @tobias_k , I agree this approach might not be better but I did what OP has asked for

Comment: He did not ask for this specifically, just wanted to point out that the regex appraoch (not just yours, but generally) is not really up to the job. That's just one example of when it will fail.

Comment: yeah I see the approach by mescalinium is better :) , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason `[\s\S]*` matches everything is because you are telling is to match either any space character (`\s`) or any non-space character (`\S`) any number of times. You can just match space with space in regex. Usually. There are exceptions, but python demands this form, so it should be fine.

You can use

```
^class ([\w]+)\([^)]+\):
```

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/aB9pX4/2

Comment: This will return all classes, but what if I want only the class with function bar2()?